# Android Converting String to JSON

Tags: java, android, json, string

I need advice into how to work out a method in Android which has to pick a string loaded with JSON data and then convert it back to JSON.

For the time being, I have programmed the following but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

```
private void convert_JSON()
    {
    String json;
    //funcions per a cridar el string amb JSON i convertir-lo de nou a JSON
    JSONArray jsas = new JSONArray(); 
    for (int i =0; i < jsas.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject message = jsas.getJSONObject(i);
        String content = message.getString("content");
    }

    }
```

The JSON is loaded into a String in this other method:

```
private void read_JSON(String json)
    {

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jso3 = new JSONArray (jObject.getString("Nombres_Hijos"));
        String name = jso3.getString("Nombre");
        System.out.println(name);

        String surname = jso3.getString("Apellidos");
        System.out.println(surname);

        int date = jso3.getInt("Año_nacimiento");
        System.out.println(date);

        JSONArray jsa2 = jso3.getJSONArray ("Nombres_Hijos");
        String names = jsa2.toString();
        for (int i=0; i < jsa2.length(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(jsa2.getString(i));  
        }
        jso3.toString(json);
    }
```

And, lastly, the JSON is created within the MainActivity.java, not as a split file yet that does work correctly:

```
private void create_JSON(String json)
    {
        JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jso.put("Nombre","Miguel");
            jso.put("Apellidos", "Garcia");
            jso.put("Año_nacimiento", 1990);
            JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray();
            jsa.put("Blur");
            jsa.put("Clur");
            jso.put("Nombres_Hijos", jsa);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jso.toString();
```

In short: what I want to know is if my method convert_JSON is on the right track or I'm misunderstanding how it's supposed to work like.

Thank you very much for your help.

Yours sincerely,

Mauro.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 13):

You can convert a jsonstring back to json using the following `JSONObject(String json)` constructor:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Just, put it inside a `try` `catch` block and you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `JSONObject` from a `String` using the *constructor*:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myString);
```

And to convert your `JSONObject` to a `String`, just use the `toString()` method:

```
String myString = json.toString();
```

Additionally, if you are trying to get a specific `String` value from the `JSONObject`, you can do this:

```
if (json.has("content"))
{
    String content = json.getString("content");
    //do something with content string
}
```

Finally, if you aren't very comfortable using `JSONObject`, I recommend using the tools provided by my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to help you parse, such as:

```
Object[] array = $.toArray(myJSONArray);
```

and

```
Map<String, ?> map = $.map(myJSONObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a pure copy/paste example have a look [here](http://json.org/java/)
Alternatively I would suggest using one of the many well documented libraries. My personal favourite is [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Plenty of examples on the net on how to use this.